# EF: Child datagridview only display unknown columns 'Count' (Label) and 'IsReadOnly' (checkbox)

Tags: datagridview, entity-framework-4, parent-child

Sorry for this dumb question. In VS2012 i have a simple project with a winform and an EF as data source. I dragged  a datagridview from the parent and it works fine. But when i drag the DGV from the navigation property to get the children information the columns are not being displayed, it only shows one column named 'Count' (Label) and another named 'IsReadOnly' (checkbox).

can you help

Comment: Please look the answer posted here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14281354/898559